# Função de grupo não funciona

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, query, oracle, oracle11c

Possuo duas tabelas.

1. Tabela: `Pedido`

   - Colunas: `IDPEDIDO`, `CLIENTE`, `DT_PEDIDO`, `FORMA_PGMT`, `CLIENTE_ID`.
2. Tabela: `Itens_Pedido`

   - Colunas: `PEDIDO_ID`, `QT_MERCADORIAS`, `MERCADORIA`, `MERCADORIA_ID`.

Preciso criar uma consulta para saber qual o produto mais vendido nos meses de Janeiro e Fevereiro de 2015. Fiz a consulta abaixo mas ela está me retornando este erro:

> "not a single-group group function"

Consulta:

```
    Select max(sum(ITENS_PEDIDO.QT_MERCADORIA)),
           ITENS_PEDIDO.MERCADORIA
      From ITENS_PEDIDO
      Join PEDIDO
        On ITENS_PEDIDO.PEDIDO_ID = PEDIDO.IDPEDIDO
     Group By ITENS_PEDIDO.MERCADORIA_IDMERCADORIA,
           ITENS_PEDIDO.MERCADORIA,
           PEDIDO.DT_PEDIDO
    Having PEDIDO.DT_PEDIDO Between to_date('01/01/2015', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
                                And to_date('28/02/2015', 'DD/MM/YYYY');
```

Comment: Segundo [essa resposta no SOEn](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20207508/sql-not-a-single-group-group-function-error) você está usando colunas que estão sendo usadas em funções agregadas no GROUP BY. Tente refazer sua query sem incluir `ITENS_PEDIDO.QT_MERCADORIA` no GROUP BY;

Comment: Isso funciona... o problema é que se eu não colocar ITENS_PEDIDO.QT_MERCADORIA ele só mostra a quantidade de mais vendido e não mostra o nome do produto.

Comment: Tente remover o `max()`, criar um alias assim `sum(ITENS_PEDIDO.QT_MERCADORIA) as total_mercadoria`  para usar `order by total_mercadoria desc limit 1`.

Comment: Não funcionou apareceu um resultado 50 que não consigo entender do porque, a soma nunca vai dar 50

Answer (score 0):

Tente simplificar a sua query:

```
Select sum(ITENS_PEDIDO.QT_MERCADORIA),
       ITENS_PEDIDO.MERCADORIA
  From ITENS_PEDIDO
       Join PEDIDO
            On ITENS_PEDIDO.PEDIDO_ID = PEDIDO.IDPEDIDO
Where PEDIDO.DT_PEDIDO Between to_date('01/01/2015', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
                           And to_date('28/02/2015', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
 Group By ITENS_PEDIDO.MERCADORIA_IDMERCADORIA,
          ITENS_PEDIDO.MERCADORIA;
```

O que foi feito:

- Remoção da função de agregação `MAX`: redundante neste caso;
- Colocação do critério de filtro para a cláusula `WHERE`: o `HAVING` deve ser somente utilizado quando o critério desejado envolve um resultado da sumarização;
- Remoção da coluna `PEDIDO.DT_PEDIDO` do `GROUP BY`: deduzo pelo fato deste campo não ser selecionado, a sumarização deve ser somente por produto, e não produto/data.